# Google Apps Script Save Attachment in Folder Duplicating files in drive

Tags: google-apps-script

When specific emails with an attachment come into my inbox, they are labeled and the script runs to move the attachments in the label to drive. This works well, however each time it runs it saves files from ALL labeled emails, which duplicates the older ones. How can i either delete duplicates in the folder, or specify only new/unread emails?

```
function saveAttachmentInFolder(){
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1sCAnEmajf-nPlnczEjlrTCvaNP8UixMp');// your Google Drive Folder ID to save the files
 var userId = "cierra.xxx@xxx.com";
 var query = "label:TEST Dallas Aerial Invoices";
 var res = Gmail.Users.Messages.list(userId, {q: query});
 res.messages.forEach(function(m){
   var attA=GmailApp.getMessageById(m.id).getAttachments();
   attA.forEach(function(a){
     folder.createFile(a.copyBlob()).setName(a.getName()); // gets name of file
   });
 });
}
```

Comment: I wrote a blog on deleting duplicate files in the drive. Maybe it can help  https://kcl.hashnode.dev/how-to-find-and-delete-duplicate-files-in-google-drive